# Custom UITableViewCell. How do I create UITableViewCell as on the screenshot

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've just added screenshot. Is it a custom cell ? As I see "Map" is right-aligned and "1800" is left alighed. How do I create it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed looks like a custom cell. Because UITableViewCell inherits from UIView, a cell has a content view. You can add your own subviews (the labels and textfields) to that contentView and lay them out programmatically or using the Interface Builder.

There are a lot of online tutorials on how to accomplish that. Just search with google for "uitableviewcell interface builder tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial will help you a lot of Table View

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html